# Implementing Observer Pattern in Android

Tags: java, android, observer-pattern

Suppose that I am creating an MVC application android application, whereby, I have two different types of users;

- Admin
- Customers

The Admins are the currently logged in user. 
Also, the Admin has a list of Customers that he is in charge of. 
Also, note Customer has three different attributes.
Also, I am using an MVC architecture.

```
Model
- Admin
- Customer
   - AttrA
   - AttrB
   - AttrC

View
- MainActivityView
- AttrAView
- AttrBView
- AttrCView

Controller
```

The requirements are that the Admin must be able to Observe the attributes of each of his patient. 
So, for example in the main view, all list of all customers are shown, and when an Admin clicks a Customer, he is given the option of Observing one of the Customers attribute.

I have identified that the way to approach this problem is by implementing an Observer pattern whereby the Attribute's (AttrA, AttrB ... ) are the Subject and the Observer is the AttrAView.

I've tried implementing the Activities as Observers, however, the Activity is only created when I visit the page and therefore, it is not able to subscribe to the Attribute (which is implementing the Subject).

edit:
Added UML. Also note, UML may have some other Classes that are not shown above.

[UML Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1wix.png)

Comment: Use LiveData from Android architecture components library or RxJava/RxAndroid library. They are the implementation of observer pattern in Android.

Comment: @Arthur is correct. Your description begs for the use of LiveData.